# Unable to access tables other then 'sqlite_master' from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I'm trying to access a SQLite database through JavaScript:

```
function executeQuery(query, callback) {
    try {
        db.transaction(function (tx) {
                tx.executeSql(query, [], function(tx, result) {
                        if (typeof(callback) == "function") callback(result);
                        else if (callback != undefined) eval(callback + "(result)");
                    }, function(tx, error) { console.log(error); });
                });
    } catch (e) {
        alert("Failed to execute query because of " + e);
    }
}
```

But despite containing several tables, the db let's me only read data from 'sqlite_master'.

```
"SELECT name, sql FROM sqlite_master;"
```

http://img593.imageshack.us/img593/646/sqlitemaster.png
(Could not insert image due to lack of rep)

Any insight on what's going on here, would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Post a complete and **self-contained** example.